# How to prevent <sup></sup> from formating text?

Tags: kotlin

ive been writing a short bot for a comunity project (PvZ 2 Eclise wiki), im writing in kotlin playground so everyone can use it, and i was writing and wanted to print out a message with code, but it automatically converts it to the font. Anyone can tell me how to stop this?

This is my code atm

```
fun main () {
    val list = listOf("RTID(ra@ZombieTypes)", "RTID(mummy_armor1@ZombieTypes)", "RTID(camel_onehump@ZombieTypes)", "RTID(ra@ZombieTypes)", "RTID(ra@ZombieTypes)")
    for (item in list)
        when (item) {
            "RTID(mummy@ZombieTypes)" -> print("{{P|Mummy zombie|2}}<sup></sup> ")
            "RTID(mummy_armor1@ZombieTypes)" -> print("{{P|Conehead mummy|2}}<sup></sup>")
            else -> print("WIP")
        }
}
```

Comment: Does `!<sup></sup> ` work? If not -- what you are looking for is called and escape character. Escape as in escape or ignore the following characters normal function.

Comment: This (likely) is just how kotlin playground displays the output.